# Error while performing registry transaction operation when creating a new API in WSO2 APIM 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I am trying to create a new API in WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0, I am getting the below error and the API doesn't get created.

[image]

But, on restarting the server, the API gets created. But I do keep facing the above issue frequently and restarting the server resolves it. Wanted to know what could be causing this issue? Also is it like I am missing out on some configurations and there is some permanent fix?

Community, appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: it seems a [bug](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9898). However, what is the username? How many characters are there?

Comment: There should be errors in wso2carbon.log. Can you post that too?

Comment: Are you facing this issue in an HA environment?

Comment: Hi Prabhashi, the username is admin.

Comment: Hi Saranki, it is a single node deployment that we have.

Comment: Can you post the error log when this issue comes up?